# Looking for specific IntellJ API Topic

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm creating a plugin(targeting WebStorm) that monitors the IDE usage and need to be notified when the user is "no longer using" the IDE, meaning he closed IDE, closed the laptop lid, turned it off, or smth along those lines.

Is there an appropriate Topic I can subscribe to to achieve this (or even better, a list of ALL the topics one can subscribe to so I could deduce what to use myself)?

Comment: It looks like you need to use some system specific API to monitor the power and process events.

Comment: Meaning there is no topic to subscribe to in order to be notified of the IDE to be closed?

Comment: When laptop lid is closed, IDE will remain running and you will not get the notification, so it will not solve your problem.

Comment: I understand that. What I'm asking is if there's a topic in the API to be notified of IDE (WebStorm application) being started up (user double clicked on the app icon) or quit (user pressed X icon / user pressed File -> Close project).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

see `com.intellij.ide.AppLifecycleListener` to be notified when application is started/stopped